# How to use this font for the chapter titles of this thesis template?

Tags: fonts, thesis

I love the organization and good conception of this [thesis template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis). I wonder if someone can show me how to use [this font](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/zallman/) for the chapter titles (only) ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this font include `X` and `Y` letters?

Comment: There us no X and Y , aparently

Comment: No, not for a thesis: you're submitting a work, a font like that would show presumptuousness.

Comment: Why is it a matter of presumptuousness ? it is just a beautiful font.

Comment: I think it is a good font for a lettrine, but not for a thesis title — except perhaps a thesis on fairy tales…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure? Add these to your preamble:

```
\input Zallman.fd
 \newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}
%   \usepackage{sectsty}
%   \chapterfont{\raggedright\initfamily}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {{\initfamily\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter \\
    \initfamily #1
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\initfamily #1
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
```

[image]

I won't do this because of this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I noticed some letters can not be printed, but since I love the font, I will change the titles that have those letters. Thank you

Comment: @begueradj You are welcome :)